# Fejer-Riesz Theorem for polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z: |z| <1\}$ and $\mathbb{T}=\{z: |z|=1\}$. Suppose $D$ and $E$ are polynomials of degree atmost $n$ with complex coefficients such that

1. $|E(z)| \leq |D(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$
2. $D(z) \ne 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Edit: 3. $E(z)=z^n\overline{E(1/\overline{z})}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Prove that there exists a polynomial $A$ that does not vanish on $\mathbb{D}$ and $|A(z)|^2=|D(z)|^2-|E(z)|^2$ for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

My attempt: By continuity arguments, the trigonometric polynomial $|D(z)|^2-|E(z)|^2 \geq 0$ for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$. In particular, $|D(z)|^2-|E(z)|^2 \geq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{T}$ . By Fejer-Riesz Theorem, there exists a polynomial $A$ that does not vanish on $\mathbb{D}$ and $|A(z)|^2=|D(z)|^2-|E(z)|^2$ for all $z \in \mathbb{T}$.

From here onwards, I think one can use maximum-modulus principle to obtain the desired inequality for $\mathbb{D}$. Any hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true; for example take $E(z)=2z-1, D(z)=z-2$ It is clear that if $|z|=1$ we have $|E(z)|=|D(z)|$ (multiply with $|\bar z|=1$ either term) but if $|z| <1$ we have $|E(z)|<|D(z)|$ (squaring for example), while $D$ doesn't vanish in the unit disc.

Then any $A$ st $|A(z)|^2=|D(z)|^2-|E(z)|^2$ would need to be identically zero on the unit circle, hence identically zero in the plane, so the equality cannot hold inside the unit disc

After the edit in the OP which changed the problem one can take $E(z)=(2z-1)(z-2)$ and $D(z)=(z-2)^2$ and now $E$ satisfies the extra condition and still the result fails

Comment: What about when $E(z)=z^n\overline{E(1/\overline{z})}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. In the example, this condition does not hold.

Comment: see edit above for an $E$ that satisfies the extra condition; however, if you want to keep getting answers, try not edit questions in such a way that existing answers do not work anymore, but ask a new question with the extra conditions - afaik this is the etiquette on this site and it's useful to follow it to keep people interested in your questions

Comment: My sincere apologies. I will keeep this in my mind in future.

Comment: No problem - it's good to ensure that answers do not become wrong of they originally were right (usually if there are trivial mistakes in the original question people point them in comments)